# C# Razor trying to populate textbox from Dropdown

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to build a EF C# Razor application.  I continue to fail in endeavor to have the dropdown box[listbox]'s choice call a route called getRecruiter(with that value) and change the recruitername textbox to the recruiter.

It errors saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: RecruiterName is not defined
If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am trying to learn how to use Razor and C# and have tried everything I could find online.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Notes Model:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace JOM.Models
{
    public class NotesModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int NotesID { get; set; }

        public int JobID { get; set; }
        public string Recruiter { get; set; }
        public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
        public string NoteData { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class JobWithRecruiter
    {
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        public string RecruiterName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notes Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using JOM.DAL;
using JOM.Models;

namespace JOM.Controllers
{
    public class NotesModelsController : Controller
    {
        private JobsContext db = new JobsContext();

        // GET: NotesModels
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<JobModel> jobs = db.Jobs;
            ViewData["jobs"] = jobs;

            return View(db.Notes.ToList());
        }

        // GET: NotesModels/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            NotesModel notesModel = db.Notes.Find(id);
            if (notesModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(notesModel);
        }

        // GET: NotesModels/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
               IEnumerable<JobModel> jobs = db.Jobs;
            ViewData["jobs"] = jobs;

            return View();
        }

        // POST: NotesModels/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "NotesID,JobID,Recruiter,NoteTitle,NoteData,ActiveDate")] NotesModel notesModel)
        {
            ViewBag.Jobs =
             from job in db.Jobs
             select job;
            ViewBag.Recruiters =
                from job in db.Jobs
                join note in db.Notes on job.JobID equals note.JobID
                select new JobWithRecruiter { JobID = job.JobID, RecruiterName = note.Recruiter };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Notes.Add(notesModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(notesModel);
        }

        // GET: NotesModels/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            NotesModel notesModel = db.Notes.Find(id);
            if (notesModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(notesModel);
        }

        // POST: NotesModels/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "NotesID,JobID,Recruiter,NoteTitle,NoteData,ActiveDate")] NotesModel notesModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(notesModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(notesModel);
        }

        // GET: NotesModels/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            NotesModel notesModel = db.Notes.Find(id);
            if (notesModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(notesModel);
        }

        // POST: NotesModels/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            NotesModel notesModel = db.Notes.Find(id);
            db.Notes.Remove(notesModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes View:

```
@model JOM.Models.NotesModel
    @using JOM.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@functions
{
    public string getRecruiter(int jobID)
    {
        if (jobID > 0)
        {
            var j = (IEnumerable<JobWithRecruiter>)ViewBag.Recruiters;
            return j.Where(jo => jo.JobID.Equals(jobID)).First<JobWithRecruiter>().RecruiterName;
        }
        return "No Name Selected";
    }
        }
<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Notes</h4>
        <hr />
        @{
            int selectedJobID = 0;
            string RecruiterName = "Not Selected";
    }
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="JobDesc">Choose Job:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
@{ 
    var jobs = (IEnumerable<JobModel>)ViewBag.Jobs;
    }
    @Html.DropDownList("listbox", jobs.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.JobID.ToString(),
    Text = item.JobDesc.ToString()
}))

                <script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#listbox').change(function () {
            selectedJobID = $(this).val();
            @{
                RecruiterName = getRecruiter(selectedJobID); 
                }
            $('#recruiter').val(RecruiterName);

        });
    });
                 </script>
               </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Recruiter", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox(RecruiterName, RecruiterName,new { ID="recruiter", @class = "form-control" });
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recruiter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NoteTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoteTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoteTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NoteData, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoteData, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoteData, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActiveDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActiveDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActiveDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke C# code like if it was JS code, so this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listbox').change(function () {
        selectedJobID = $(this).val();
        @{
            RecruiterName = getRecruiter(selectedJobID); 
            }
        $('#recruiter').val(RecruiterName);

    });
});
```

doesn't mean `RecruiterName = getRecruiter(selectedJobID);` will be assigned when you change value of `#listbox` dropdown.

What you could do is preparing JSON collection containing all your recruiters inside controller and pass it to your view. Then you could use only JS (which would work used like you tried with C# code) to retrieve recruiters name based on ID.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

In controller invoke list:

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult bindCityList(int stateid)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstcity = new List<SelectListItem>();
        try
        {
            Panel cs = new Panel();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = cs.getCityVsState(Conn, stateid);
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                lstcity.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = @dr["CityName"].ToString(), Value = @dr["CityID"].ToString() });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.WriteErrorToFile("Panel::bind City List :" + ex.Message.ToString());

        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
        return Json(lstcity.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

In view --
On change of state  dropdown bind city list

```
  $('#ddlstate').change(function () {
        var url = "bindCityList";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { stateid: $('#ddlstate').val() },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ddlcity").empty();
                var markup = "<option value='0'>---Select---</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value='" + data[x].Value + "'>" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }

                $("#ddlcity").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
```